# Task.Factory.StartNew() not working for me

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I wrote this small application. for some reason i am not being able to print "Hello from a thread" when i run this program. however if i debug it and put a breakpoint inside Do() method, it does print.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Do);
        }

        private static void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from a thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your application ends before the thread spins up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure that the program simply isn't closing before you can see the output? Because this works fine for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Do);
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from a thread");
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit: Added the comment I wrote in response to this, including my reasoning to why the text wasn't printed.*

Its either because the application closes down before the thread has the possibility of outputting the string to the screen. It's also possible that you simply cant see it because it closes straight away. Either way the reason it worked with the breakpoint is because you keep the application alive longer.

Comment: yes, Console.Read(); resolved it.
can you please elaborate why i need it? thanks!

Comment: Its either because the application closes down before the thread has the possibility of outputting the string to the screen. It's also possible that you simply cant see it because it closes straight away. Either way the reason it worked with the breakpoint is because you keep the application alive longer.

Comment: Because after you start the task your program return from the main function and exits. But Do is called async on another thread, but to late your program is already terminated.

Comment: @user829174: you need it for stop the execution of your **program** and wait for user input. In this way you can *see*, actually, what was printed out on console.

Comment: A more secure way to ensure the task has actually finished is caching the newly created `Task` in a local variable and call `Wait()` on it before exiting `Main`. This doesn't require the user to do a thing (useful on server machines) and is totally safe, especially if it's a very time expensive task (because it will definitely wait for the task to finish, even if the user hits a key before the task is done)

Comment: @user829174, basically yes. But it's actually more complicated than that. If you want to know more, read about `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Even when running the original application from a cmd.exe window the message is not printed so it's more likely that the application is closing down before the thread starts as others have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Do);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from a thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? StartNew(Do) will run Do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx

Comment: I tried, and it didn't run, or well it ran, but not the new thread. It's possible that it depends on OS/Hardware.

Comment: I would check the comments in the post I did above, as you put the ReadKey in the Do() function and not in the Main, it's possible that the Thread never has time to actually call the function before the application closes.

Comment: Heh, yea that's much better. :)